# How to import from a python script that requires command line input

Tags: python, ipython

As an example: I have a python script scip.py with

```
from sys import argv

# parsing the input
script, NU = argv

def main(NU):
    return 

def somefunc():
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(NU)
```

Assume I am in a [I]python shell. I can run the script e.g. via `run scip.py 1` . But how can I import the functions from it? `import scip` fails, because it needs variables to unpack. `import scip 1` gives a SyntaxError.

Comment: "Doctor, it hurts when I do this". Move the `script, NU = argv` line inside `if __name__ == '__main__'` check.

Comment: Oh yes sure, that solves it. But I hope, I don't run into other trouble later.

Comment: Why would you run into trouble? When you include this from another module you would use args from that script. Right? Otherwise what is the use of abstracting these functions.

Comment: Think about it logically. What should happen, conceptually, when you run the script? What should happen, conceptually, when you import it? In particular, why would you expect to look at `sys.argv` when you import it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do the trick:

```
def main(NU):
    return 

def somefunc():
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from sys import argv

    # parsing the input
    script, NU = argv
    main(NU)
```